# SSRS 2008 R2 how to get rid of dialog box when opening reports

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I can open and view reports and see the data no problem, but I'm running sql server 2008 R2 Reporting Services which is prompting the user for a login id and password.  I have the reports on a separate server than the databases, so that may be part of the issue.  I've been all over google looking for a solution with no success as of yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Does anybody know how to get rid of the dialog boxes, the prompts asking for username and password?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error in Internet Explorer you need to check how the **User Authentication** is set in **Internet Options -> Security Settings**:

[image]

If it's set to `Automatic logon with current user name and password` you shouldn't be prompted.

Obviously there are security considerations here!

Here's a useful link: [Enter Credentials](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/878c6a48-892b-4c98-b0b4-3de55ab4f83a).

Also, make sure your **Data Source** is not set to `Connect using Credentials supplied by the user running the report`:

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing your reports?

Comment: @KendrickLamar, my reports are deployed at client sites; they will typically access these through a Winforms ReportViewer control embedded in our C# application, but there's nothing stopping them accessing them through their Report Manager website; I know a number do this as well. For this second case I have had to send details of the above IE configuration change more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you are using the ReportViewer control inside a windows forms application to render the reports. Also, the user may choose to log into the SSRS Report Manager to view the report directly.

In that case my suggestion would be to use Custom Security inside of SSRS. If you have the time to implement the authentication then both your forms app and the ssrs manager could make use of your new authentication process.

[SSRS 2008 R2 custom security example](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008R2!Security%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home)

The other options have been stated by [Ian Preston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228274/ian-preston). You either require the user to log in using a windows account or give them unfettered access to your reports.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.